# Does Blogger provide a way to check browser type and version?

Tags: blogger

I'm googling for any mention of whether or not Blogger provides a way for checking browser type and version, but nothing is coming up. Maybe someone here has the definitive "yes" or "no" on this? And if "yes", maybe provide a brief example?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
a JavaScript code for detecting browser of visitor?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
browsername=navigator.appName;
if (browsername.indexOf("Netscape")!=-1) {browsername="NS"}
else
{if (browsername.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {browsername="MSIE"}
else {browsername="N/A"}};
// Browserdetectionscript made by Henrik Petersen / NetKontoret
// Script explained at www.echoecho.com/javascript.htm
// Please do not remove this and the two lines above.
// Detect the browsername
browserversion="0";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("2.")!=-1) {browserversion="2"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("3.")!=-1) {browserversion="3"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("4.")!=-1) {browserversion="4"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("5.")!=-1) {browserversion="5"};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("6.")!=-1) {browserversion="6"};

// Send visitor to relevant pages
if (browsername=="NS") {window.location="http://stackoverflow.com"};
if (browsername=="MSIE"){
  if (browserversion<4){window.location="http://www.google.com"}
  else {window.location="http://www.facebook.com"}
}
if (browsername=="N/A") {window.location="http://www.aslamise.blogspot.com"};
</script>
```

if not , let us know,what you need to do with it.
if yes, upvote and mark as accepted answer. :)